# Is there a way to pass variables / $_POST through foreach statements?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, I'm getting my feet wet with PHP, and was wondering if it was possible if I could put
`$id = $row['id'];` through a `$_POST` statement,then getting each `$_POST` variable, and then printing them through a `foreach`.

Thanks in advance!

order.php:

```
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $food = $row["food"];
            $price = $row["price"];
            $picture = $row["picture"];
            $id = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>
                    <td><img src='$picture' width='120px' /></td>
                    <td>$food</td>
                    <td>$$price</td>
                    <td><input type='number' min='0' max='10' placeholder='#' name='$id' maxlength='1'></td>
                </tr>";
        }
```

action.php:

```
            foreach ($rows as $row){
              $food = $row['food'];
              $price = $row['price'];
              $id = $row['id'];

              if(isset($_POST[$id])){
                $qty = $_POST[$id];
                echo 'set';
                echo $qty;
              }else{
                  echo 'unset';
                  $qty = '';

              }
              echo "<tr>
            <td>$food</td>
            <td>$qty</td>
            <td>$price</td>
        </tr>";      
        }
```

Comment: Either I am too stupid to understand, or this question is too unclear.

Comment: I think the input is a quantity field. When the form is submitted you want to be able to get the quantity associated with each id. Is that correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245657/loop-through-post?rq=1

Comment: @jd182 exactly! I'm trying to echo the variable $id for each row

Comment: What I don't get is, you posted the same question (code) multiple times, accepted all the answers, but still it seems that they haven't fixed your actual problem. Will we be expecting another question in an another hour?

Comment: More like `triplicate` if not `quad` - @SyntaxLAMP ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your echo to this:

```
echo "<tr>
       <td><img src='$picture' width='120px' /></td>
       <td>$food</td>
       <td>$$price</td>
       <td><input type='number' min='0' max='10' placeholder='#' name='qty[".$id."]' maxlength='1'></td>
      </tr>";
```

Then in your action.php:

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
          $food = $row['food'];
          $price = $row['price'];
          $id = $row['id'];

          if(isset($_POST['qty'][$id])){
            $qty = $_POST['qty'][$id];
            echo 'set';
            echo $qty;
          }else{
              echo 'unset';
              $qty = '';

          }
          echo "<tr>
        <td>$food</td>
        <td>$qty</td>
        <td>$price</td>
    </tr>";      
}
```